# Orthogonality Check in MMSE

Tags: estimation

We want to estimate non-random parameter $x_0$ based on the following measurements: $\\$

$z_i = x_0 * exp(-t_i) + v_i$ where $t_i$ is a constant, $v_i$ is white noise with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$ and $i = 1,2$. I'm trying to confirm the orthogonality principle based on the following estimator: $\\$
$\hat{x}_0 = k*exp(t_1)*z_1 + (1-k)*exp(t_2)*z_2$. Since the orthogonality principles states that the error is orthogonal to the observations: $\\$

$E[(\hat{x}_0 - x_0) * z_1] = 0$ $\\$

$E[(k*exp(t_1)*z_1^2 + (1-k)*exp(t_2)*z_1 *z_2 - x_0*z_1]$
$ = k*exp(t_1)*(\sigma_1^2 + x_0^2 * exp(-2t_1)) + (1-k)*exp(t_2) * x_0^2 * exp(-t_1) * exp(-t_2) - x_0^2 * exp(-t_1)$ which gives us $k*exp(t_1) * \sigma^2 = 0.$ But I know that k is different than zero. What's wrong in here?

Comment: To what "orthogonality principle" are you referring?  Do you have a source?  (I suspect you might have misinterpreted a result from ordinary least squares regression.)  In what sense is $t_i$ "constant," given you index it?

Comment: @whuber the following link explains the principle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality_principle and $t_i$ is a non-random scalar(it's time).

Comment: Thank you.  Are you implying you have only two observations?  What is $k$ and how does that make $\hat x_0$ a Bayes estimator?

Comment: Yes, we have two observations which are taken at $t_1$ and $t_2$. $k$ is just another non-random scalar. The optimal value of $k$ minimizes the mean square estimation error, i.e $E[(\hat{x}_0 - x_0)^2]$. By the orthogonality principle, the error $(\hat{x}_0 - x_0)$, should be orthogonal to the observations.

Comment: I can't tell what you are treating as random and what not.  In particular, you refer to "orthogonal to the observations" (*plural*) but your expectation involves only $z_1.$ The whole formulation is puzzling.

Comment: I just put the derivation for $z_1$. However, by the same logic, $E[(\hat{x}_0 - x_0) * z_2] = 0$ should also be true. Just to eliminate the confusion, $x_0, t_1, t_2$ are constants. $v_1, v_2$ are random.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123318/discussion-between-eet-and-whuber).